# how can I use IF ELSE to select stages in the yml file?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

can I use if-else statment to run different stages during pipeline execution?

If variable value from another .yml parameter is "yes" then  execute first stage otherwise execute second stage.

I've the following code in my yaml file:

```
trigger:
  batch: true

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: DevOpsEngineering/azure-pipeline_templates
stages:
if (true)
  - stage: Test1
    jobs:
else        
  - stage: Test2
    jobs:
```

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? It explains how conditionals work.

Comment: This question does not make sense. You mention parameters where the value is set yet the sample code shows no parameters. Please provide further clarification so we can better assist. Stages can be conditionally executed if the value is known at pipeline expansion.